# mod_rewrite works in Linux but not in Windows

Tags: windows, apache, mod-rewrite, windows-7-x64, apache2.4

Everyone knows the black magic of Apache and mod_rewrite...

Also I have a problem too...

I just downloaded Apache 2.4 from here https://www.apachelounge.com/download/win64/ and enabled mod_rewrite with this line

`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Output of httpd.exe -v

`Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Win64)
Apache Lounge VC10 Server built:   Jul 19 2014 12:25:58`

My httpd.conf http://pastebin.com/TDHpurBi

And my .htaccess http://pastebin.com/f6KV3Zd2

The .htaccess is for my MVC-Framework

Thanks in advance for any help

PS: The .htaccess worked like a charm with

`Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Win32)
Apache Lounge VC10 Server built:   Nov 26 2013 15:46:56`

from Uniserver

PS2: I forgot to say, that I got the .htaccess running under Linux with the enabled AllowOverride in httpd.conf. So it might be only a Apache-Windows-problem.

Comment: I would imagine there is a difference in server configuration. A point-release very rarely (and should be never) breaks a feature.

Comment: I forgot to say, that I got the .htaccess running under Linux. :/

Comment: Make sure update the question with relevant information/details.

Comment: I bet it's because of relative paths with `ServerRoot`, `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` directives. Try with absolute paths instead, which should be working on both OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem!

```
DocumentRoot "${SRVROOT}/htdocs"
<Directory "${SRVROOT}/htdocs">
```

section!

And there set

```
AllowOverride All
```

this will solve your problem!

Comment: Could you explain a little more about how this works?

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider alias and position of .htaccess

so, for example, if you have created an alias called "mywebsite" (so you will open http://localhost/mywebsite to reach the homepage) but you have .htaccess inside a subfolder, for example /api folder, you need to use this RewriteBase directive :

RewriteBase /mywebsite/api

and then restart apache